# How to get if category has posts?

Tags: posts, categories

I have problem with getting `get_category('2')->category_count` number. I want to have list of news which are as a **post** in one **category**. I use plugin for insert php (I know it can be used by theme). I also know it's not best solution how to do it, but I don't have time for it and I'm not so friendly with Wordpress.

But I have to hide headline of News & updates when there is no posts in that specific category. I get that number from `get_category('2')->category_count` only If I put it above `query_post('cat=2');`.

**EDIT:**

Now I put into theme in index.php, so its not in post.

```
<?php
get_header();

cn_include_content(116);

$news = get_posts('category_name=news-updates'); if ($news): ?>
<div id="news-updates" class="row">
<h2 class="main-headline">News &amp; updates</h2>
<div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
  <?php

    query_posts('cat=2');

    while (have_posts()) : the_post();

      echo '<div class="news"><div class="news-headline">';
      the_title(sprintf('<h3><a href="%s">', esc_url(get_permalink())), '</a></h3>');
      echo '<span>';
      the_date();
      echo '</span>';
      echo '</div>';
      the_excerpt();
      echo '</div>';

    endwhile;

    //            the_posts_pagination([
    //              'prev_text' => __('Previous page', 'twentyfifteen'),
    //              'next_text' => __('Next page', 'twentyfifteen'),
    //              'before_page_number' => '<span class="meta-nav screen-reader-text">' . __('Page', 'twentyfifteen') . ' </span>',
    //            ]);

  ?>

</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry but I have to downvote this kind of approach, since it looks like you're only looking for a quick fix to maintain the bad practice, like `query_posts()` and executing php code from the content.

Comment: This approach is just very very bad, but it is a hackers dream. Won't be supriced if you get hacked soon

Comment: It's for web which will be online only for 2 months, so I don't care about it. I don't want to waste my time on it.

Comment: But yes, you are right, but still I don't know how to solve it without do it as should be.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You just need add if condition here, check the following code

```
    query_posts('cat=2');
if(have_posts()) { /*continue with while code*/  } //end of if
```

Comment: This is a really poor approach. Please search this site for `query_posts` and see how really bad it realy is

Comment: It doesn't work. I don't know why, but it show every post many times

Comment: ok, after change how to put it on index it works :D